# If conditions with range

Tags: php

I have code:

```
$firstletter = mb_substr($userData['name'], 0, 1, 'UTF-8');
if ($firstletter=='א') {
    ...
}
if ($firstletter=='a') {
    ...
}
```

and I want to make the if in range, like:

```
if($firstletter>'a' && $firstletter<'c')
```

or

```
if($firstletter>'א' && $firstletter<'ה')
```

it's possible to write this?

Comment: Run the code and see what happens.

Comment: Why people asks before try ?

Comment: I'm learning stages, and am interesting to know if it is possible

Comment: This question has been asked 4 times so far today.... it should be as easy for you to try it yourself as it is to ask, and then you're not wasting other peoples' time

Answer (score 4):

yes it is possible and you just wrote it.

Comment: Yes, you will need to look at an ascii map to be sure the characters exist in the range you are looking for.

Comment: so I need to write with the hebrew letter or with the ascii code its?

Comment: @IdanNeeman The letter should be fine - Omar's point is that when you're comparing if a string is greater to another string, they'll be ranked according to the respective order of their ASCII values.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ord()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php) function that returns ASCII code of letter passed. But you have to be sure that only Latin letters are passed. For unicode support check out comments on ord() function